# Add locales to section causes error

Tags: localization

Just Playing around with Craft and get this kind of error:

If I create a new locale and go to add it to a previously made section I get

> Internal Server Error -> Undefined offset: 0

I noticed that if I create a section after adding the locale I can then edit/remove/re-add locales without errors

(I'm on osx MAMP PRO - php 5.3.28 a module)

Comment: Can you reproduce the error with devMode enabled, then submit a ticket from your dashboard's Get Help widget so we can see if it's a bug in Craft?

Comment: I'm setting up a new environment to replicate the issue

Comment: getting the exact same error in the exact same scenario. Also, for whatever reason I can't get devMode recognised from my general.php file, only when I set it to true for the * array.

Comment: submitted an error report as requested above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug that's been fixed in the next (post [2.3.2635](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2635)) release of Craft.